# Display List and transformation

Tags: opengl

Whenever, I enter a transformation (gltranslate, glrotate, glscale) within a display list, the transformation remains as a command within the display list.  Everytime the display list is rendered, it will calculate all and over again.

Is there a way, I can make an opengl transformation and the transformed vertex coordinates be stored permanently in a display list instead of transformation & intial coordinates?

Comment: How can you tell what the internal format of the display list data is?  All you have is an opaque handle, right?

Answer (score 3):

Apply your matrix transforms [manually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) to your vertexes before submitting them to a display list.

But Drew Hall is right: the driver is probably already doing something similar when it compiles your display lists.

Comment: It probably isn't, actually. Display list implementation is one of those things that is really hard to get right and optimized at the same time, because there are too many corner cases to handle. Examples of issues: 1. there is nothing ensuring the GL that the rotation will target the MODELVIEW matrix. If PROJECTION is active before the glCallList, then the behavior has to be different. 2. The rotation needs to be active after the display list execution, at the top of the matrix stack... And I'm sure I don't think of all corner cases.